# How to access to "this" variable outside the object

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm making a js canvas plugin, and I made this object:

```
function MyObject(argument) {
   var self = this;

   var callback = argument.callback;

   this.onRequestAnimationFrame = function() {
       callback(self);
   }

   this.myFunction = function (){
       return false;
   }
}
```

and I call it like this

```
var customObject = new MyObject({
    callback: function(instanceClass){
       instanceClass.myFunction();
    }
})
```

The problem is, I must get the instance class and call a function from it, but I get "myFunction is not a function" from the console.

Comment: that code works well on my devtools console

Comment: The code that i have now written works, but it's similar to my original one, should i post it entirely? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't access "this" from outside the object.

The way you have written this, you need to instance the object, at which point myFunction will be a method of the object.

"this" is not a variable, but a keyword.

```js
function MyObject(argument) {
   var self = this;

   var callback = argument.callback;

   this.onRequestAnimationFrame = function() {
       callback(self);
   }

   this.myFunction = function (){
       return false;
   }
}

function callback (caller) {
    console.log(caller.myFunction());
};

var a = new MyObject({callback : callback});
```

Comment: Yep, "*this is not a variable*", it's a property of an execution context. ;-)

Comment: Well, the problem is that the variable self containing the keyword this has no methods, either if I console.log it inside my class.

Answer (score 0):

When we make a constructor call, if we are not returning any object then function returns a 'this' object which is in its lexical scope.

when you write this,

```
var customObject = new MyObject({
    callback: function(instanceClass){
       instanceClass.myFunction();
    }
});
```

function MyObject returns its 'this' object.

So, we can call 'onRequestAnimationFrame' function which in return call the callback.

```
customObject.onRequestAnimationFrame();
```

jsbin link: 
http://jsbin.com/foxupakihi/edit?js,console